# Navbar bootstrap example - including logos/images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am testing out bootstrap, and getting a feel for the code that runs with it.

I did a simple test with my IDE to see how the content works within the browsers.  I love the look and feel, and was wondering how code like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

with CSS like this:

```
    element.style {
    }
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
a {
  color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  background-color: transparent;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheeta:-webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: auto;
}
Inherited from 
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from 
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
:after, :before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
:after, :before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I went ahead and changed the nav brand class to:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.gif" width="238" height="50" alt=""/></a>
```

Thus removing the text, and replacing it with the image (sized accordingly) but it seems to have left the container of the main element.

Is this the proper way to format a header containing an image in bootstrap, or am I taking the easy way out and getting poor results because of it?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image) it is the right way. You need to style,position the <img /> element.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can I do that to contain it inside the frame of the nav I created?

Answer (score 0):

for an image it should be

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="...">
  </a>
</div>
```

and then in the css define the size of the image

```
.navbar-brand img{
height: ;
width: ;
}
```

this is how i have done it in the past and seems to work effectively. you might have to play around with the size, and margins to position correctly